# How to reach a function in an outer scope with data from the inner scope?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I am wondering how I can send data to a callback function defined in an outer scope, from within an inner scope.

Here is a minimum example as it is easier to describe with code:

```
from somelib import CreateWebserver, Collector


def collector_callback(code):
    # I want to affect some change to the server from this function
    # i.e. server.close()
    print(code)


def main():
    server = CreateWebserver()
    # The signature for this callback was defined by the library and I can't change it
    collector = Collector(collector_callback)
    # Blocks forever
    collector.listen()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

In the above example I create my program in a `main` function.

I am using a library with a `Collector` class.  The class takes a callback that is called when an event happens and the signature of this function is defined by the library (I can't change it).

Let's say the callback is called with a random number, and I want to do something to the server if the number is bigger than 5.

How do I access the `server` object in the `collector_callback` function?

It seems like the only way to do this would be to make the server a global variable, which I do not want to do because I want to keep things encapsulated.

Is there a better way to reach the `server` object in this instance, given than the `collector_callback` will only be called with the random number?

Comment: The typical scenario in cases such as this is to pass the arguments that need to be fed to the callback method into the class, and have the class pass those arguments into the callback method whenever it's executed.

Comment: Maybe try using the [global](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_keyword_global.asp) keyword?

Comment: Define another function inside `main` which has access to the `server` variable, and which calls `collector_callback` if the condition is true. Pass *it* as callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to create a function where one of the parameters is set and is not in the resulting function's signature

```
def collector_callback(server, code):
    server.close()
    print(code)


def main():
    server = CreateWebserver()
    callback = functools.partial(collector_callback, server)
    # callback is now a function with only one parameter "code"
    # server is always passed as the first parameter to collector_callback
    # when it is called
    collector = Collector(callback)
```